# Assigning slices of an array to a new array

Tags: ada, gnat

I have the syntax wrong but can't seem to find a informative page on the correct syntax of my question. I have a function I'm working on that takes in an array and I want to do some calculations on a slice of that array, so I thought to just create an array of a slice from the array passed in, specifically those indices. Could someone help me out on the syntax here cause this one keeps telling me `missing ','`

```
p1: UnboundArray(1 .. 15);
p1DataBits: UnboundArray(1 .. 7);
begin
    p1DataBits := (p1(3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 | 13 | 15));
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to copy some elements of one array to another using [slices](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-1-2.html). Because none of the elements are consecutive, you would likely be better off [aggregating](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-3-3.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54849431/230513), or [concatenating](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-3.html) the desired elements.

```
 p1DataBits : UnboundArray(1 .. 7) := p1(3) & p1(5) & p1(7) …;
```

You may have misread the [syntax](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-1-1-4.html) for a [*discrete_range*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6-1.html); in this context the `|` symbol "separates alternative items" rather the representing a literal [delimiter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Delimiters/vertical_line).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without expensive concatenation is to assign a direct, explicit array expression:

```
procedure Odds is
  type UnboundArray is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;
  p1: UnboundArray(1 .. 15);
  p1DataBits: UnboundArray(1 .. 7);
begin
  p1DataBits := (p1(3), p1(5), p1(7), p1(9), p1(11), p1(13), p1(15));
end;
```